# How to make pedestrian jump over walls in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Im making zone evacuation proyect, i need the human factor of "fit person" that will try to jump over litle fences represented as walls, any idea how to make this happend?

I tried changing the high of the wall, but i do not thing that is the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is to use restricted areas instead of walls.

You can add a condition for the pedestrians that can cross this restricted area based on whether they are fit or not...

The height of the wall doesn't matter, it will always be an obstacle

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "jumping" is nothing that Pedestrians can do inherently.

You'd need to model something like that from scratch, which would not be trivial.

Instead, think if you can design a "workaround" where pedestrians slow or stop in certain places, mimicking a jump.